# php utf-8 problem: UTF-8 is everywhere, but mb_strpos is always ===false. Why?

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm working with Cyrillic Bulgarian strings.

I want to compare `$words[$i]` (added: *$words is an array of strings, $words[$i] is a string*) if it contains symbols from `$cyrillic_symbols`.

```
$cyrillic_symbols="абвгдежз"; //OK!

$siglesymb=mb_substr($words[$i],9,1,'UTF-8'); //OK! "д" letter received.

echo $siglesymb; //and д displayed in the browser, OK!

echo mb_strpos($cyrillic_symbols,$siglesymb,0,'UTF-8');
```

Nothing is displayed because I think it's `== false`. I don't understand the reason why.

```
echo mb_strpos($cyrillic_symbols,"д",0,'UTF-8');
```

The same as above, but the result is not `false`, but 4 because of fifth position of д in the "абвгдежз".

The total result is: `д4`. Why?

Why the result is not `д44`?

Any ideas how to make it `д44`?

Comment: echo "<br>".$i."<br>"; echo $words[$i];

Comment: Here is a value of $i and $words[$i] as you asked: 
echo "<br>".$i."<br>";
echo $words[$i];
0
& l t ; b & g t ; д о б р & l t ; / b & g t ;   //(remove spaces), letter д is by number 9 starting from 0.

All the rest is the same: once you replace "д" on a variable $siglesymb which is actually should be "д", mb_strpos can't find it in the string.

Comment: Works fine for me if I fill in 'дддддддддддддддддд' for `$words[$i]`.

Comment: Please post your words into your question, this is hard to read in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. I would never guess it will help, but it helped... I don't understand actually why...

```
$cyrillic_symbols="абвгд";
$cyrillic_for_display=iconv('cp1251','utf-8',$symbols_non_utf);//that's a solution!
echo $cyrillic_symbols; //rectangles are displayed
echo $cyrillic_for_display; //абвгд
```

P.S. on top of php file was:

```
header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");//yes, UTF-8.
```

As I understand from all the posts above, nobody had such problem.

Moreover, UTF-8 was everywhere in files (except some fields in the MySQL db which where actually cp125, but I didn't take any data from there, although it was connected).

If someone knows the reason why cp125 appeared, please post your opinion here.

Thank you everybody. You helped me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

works for me:

```
$cyrillic_symbols="абвгдежз";
$words = preg_split('/[ ,.;]+/', 'да работи да');

foreach($words as $word) {
    for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($word,'UTF-8'); $i++) {

        $siglesymb = mb_substr($word,$i,1,'UTF-8');
        echo $siglesymb.' ';
        var_dump( mb_strpos($cyrillic_symbols,$siglesymb,0,'UTF-8') );
        echo ", ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

outputs:

```
д int(4) , а int(0) ,
р bool(false) , а int(0) , б int(1) , о bool(false) , т bool(false) , и bool(false) ,
д int(4) , а int(0) ,
```

maybe something with your input?

Comment: I copied exactly this code to my php file, put it on top, then put exit(); to interrupt the code below. The result is:
��ool(false) , 
� bool(false) , �ool(false) , 
�bool(false) , 


That's driving me crazy. Can't understand the problem.
(Offtopic: Guys, I'm sorry I'm still not a pro with this web-site, everything is new for me... I'm trying to answer all the questions you ask...)...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't had problems; please, compare to your code:

```
$cyrillic_symbols="абвгдежз"; //OK!

$words = array("абвгдабвгд");  // my test
$i = 0;

$siglesymb=mb_substr($words[$i],9,1,'UTF-8'); //OK! "д" letter received.

echo $siglesymb; //and д displayed in the browser, OK!

echo mb_strpos($cyrillic_symbols,$siglesymb,0,'UTF-8');  //4 

echo mb_strpos($cyrillic_symbols,"д",0,'UTF-8');         //4
```